# How to increment object fields in drools

Tags: java, node.js, json, drools

I'm new to drools, I want to assign incremented value to Count when the condition is satisfied and I want to do that in drools
Basically, I want to perform the below actions when amt is greater than remainingAmt, in drools

```
if (amt < remainingAmt){
                          let responseObject = {
                          result: true,
                          Count: deposit++,
                          remainingAmt: remainingAmt - amt,
                          message: 'The proceess successfully initiated',
                          Amount: amt
                        }}
```

Below is my code, but I'm not getting the proper results.

```
rule "rule2"
    dialect "mvel"
    no-loop true
    when
        u : User( )
        c : Amount( amt < u.remainingAmt )
    then
        modify( u ) {
                setResult( true ), 
                setAmt(getDeposit()+1)
                setMessage( "The proceess successfully initiated" ), 

        }
end
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do what you are looking for. You almost got it.

One possibility is to bind a variable for the `deposit` in the LHS of the rule and to increment it when modifying your `User` in the RHS:

```
rule "rule2"
    dialect "mvel"
    no-loop true
    when
        u : User( currentDeposit: deposit)
        c : Amount( amt < u.remainingAmt )
    then
        modify( u ) {
                setResult( true ), 
                setAmt(currentDeposit + 1)
                setMessage( "The proceess successfully initiated" ), 
        }
end
```

Hope it helps,